# Is a HTTP 405 status response allowed to have a body?

Tags: httpresponse, http-status-codes

I am building a RESTful API. When the client uses an unsupported method such as POST on a resource that does not supports it, I am returning a `405` with the `Allow` header which lists the allowed methods:

```
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Mon, 08 Apr 2013 00:19:26 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Is it allowed to have a body (to provide an error message) for `405` responses?

From the [w3c's site](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), it is not apparent whether a body is allowed for `405` responses.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[The HTTP/1.1 protocol spec states in the "message length" section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4):

> Any response message which "MUST NOT" include a message-body (the 1xx, 204, and 304 responses and any response to a HEAD request) is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields, regardless of the entity-header fields present in the message.

A message body is optional for all 4xx-5xx codes as long as the HTTP method is not `HEAD`.

Comment: The link is not pointing to the right section of the spec. The quote is from section 4.4: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4